# How to change DB connection in node js dynamically?

Tags: node.js, express

I have two enterprises, and both have separate DBs. And when I select these enterprises through the drop-down, I want to change my DB connection with that option.

Comment: It depends on your database driver. I believe that most of them could give you multiple connection instances if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const conn = require('./connection.js'); // your path

 conn.changeUser({database : 'databasename'}, function(err) { 
     if (err) throw err; 
   });
```

Comment: is this possible to username & password of db?

Comment: ** yes you can do.**

user: The name of the new user (defaults to the previous one).

password: The password of the new user (defaults to the previous one).
charset: The new charset (defaults to the previous one).
database: The new database (defaults to the previous

Comment: Shubham can you please show you connection.js file, I am handling same thing with a bit different funtionality.